# Where to define Query Rule and when?

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search, query

We can define Query rule in three places:

1. Search Site > Site Settings > Search > Query Rules
2. Search Site > Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Search Query Rules
3. Search Service Application > Queries and Results > Query Rules

What is the difference in all of above options?
Which option is appropriate in what situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the rule:

- If you define them in the search service, its valid for all
  webapplications associated with that search service.
- If you define it on subsite/web level, its valid for the contextual
        search made on that site.
- If you define it on site collection its
        valid for the site and all subsites.

Comment: Hi guys, i have defined my query rules at site collection level and now for some reasons I cants access them and when I go to CA I cant see them, any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Creating a query rule in SharePoint 2013 will render the Visual Best bet.The detailed steps for creating a query rule for Visual Best bet are outlined in below link
http://www.techbubbles.com/sharepoint/creating-a-query-rule-for-visual-best-bet-in-sharepoint-2013/
and 
http://www.findwise.com/blog/query-rules-in-sharepoint-2013/